# How can I use the UNIX shell to count the number of times a letter appears in a text file?

Tags: unix, word-count

I have a few text files and I'd like to count how many times a letter appears in each?

Specifically, I'd like to use the UNIX shell to do this, in the form of: cat file | .... do stuff...

Is there a way I can get the wc command to do this?

Comment: cat file | is a no go, no do, do not even think of it. Mostly it is used with less or grep, where the cat is not needed. Please do not use cat if you dont want to simply output the file.

Comment: cat is actually useful for keeping RAM usage at a minimum. It's useful when working with big files as it will feed in through the pipe line by line.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
grep char -o filename | wc -l
```

Comment: Note for those initially confused like me, replace "char" with the character or string you are looking for.

Comment: Also, most grep implementations have a "-c" option to count.

Comment: The above also works for strings, so `grep <string> -o <file> | wc -l` is the generic version. Eg: `grep , -o myfile.txt | wc -l` counts the number of commas in myfile.txt and `grep abcd -o myfile.txt | wc -l` counts the number of `abcd`s in myfile.txt

Comment: How do I modify this if want to count number of (.)s periods/full stop characters?  I want get approximate number of sentences in a document. Thanks!

Comment: @Michaël `grep -c` doesn't count multiple occurrences on the same line, unfortunately

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative:

```
tr -d -C X <infile | wc -c
```

where X is the character or string of characters you want to count and infile is the input file.

Comment: This is cleaner than the accepted answer (which relies on the fact that the output of `grep -o` is newline-separated). This also works with ANY character (including `\n`)

Comment: Interpretation: "delete (`-d`) everything except for characters of type X (`-C`), then count the number of remaining characters (`wc -c`)."

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to grep:

```
sed 's/[^x]//g' filename | tr -d '\012' | wc -c
```

where `x` is the character you want to count.

Answer (score 1):

There's also awk:

```
$ echo -e "hello world\nbye all" | awk -Fl '{c += NF - 1} END {print c}'
5
```

Change `-Fl` to `-F<your character>`.

This works by setting the field delimiter to the character specified by `-F`, then accumulating the number of fields on each line - 1 (because if there's one delimiter, there are two fields - but we should only count 1).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ printf "%s\n", gsub( "ur_char", "oth_char", $0 ) }' < your_file_name > output.txt
```

you can add count of current line number to get the line numbers in awk also.

Answer (score 1):

echo "a/b/c/d/e/f/g" | awk -F"/" '{print NF}'

this will give the number of occurrence of character "/"

Answer (score 1):

In this case, i'am counting the character "|":

```
expr `wc -c < filename` \- `tr -d \| < filename | wc -c`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try easily:
`grep -c 'YOUR LETTER' YOUR FILE`

Comment: the number will appear on the shell, in the newline

Comment: will result in number of lines containing the character, and not number of character instances

Answer (score 0):

try it with

```
grep  [PATTERN] -o [FILE] | wc -l
```

and please do not use cat if not needed.

Comment: it doesn't count multiple characters per line

Comment: @samoz:cat is wrong, since it should input the read file to another program - the other program is able to read the file by itself, so the use of cat is unneeded and complicates the codeline. 
@SilentGhost: your right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
cat  input_file | \
awk 'BEGIN {FS="x"; var=0 } \
{if (NF>0){ var=var + (NF-1) } } \
END{print var}'
```

where X is the character or string of characters you want to count and infile is the input file