# Counting the number of occurrences of a character in multiple files with unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to help out my girlfriend - she needs the specific count of certain characters in around 200 files (per file).

I already found [How can I use the UNIX shell to count the number of times a letter appears in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368563/how-can-i-use-the-unix-shell-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-letter-appears-in-a), but that only shows the complete number, not the number of occurrences per file. basically, what I want is the following:

```
$ ls 
test1   test2
$ cat test1
ddddnnnn
ddnnddnnnn
$ cat test2
ddnnddnnnn
$ grep -o 'n' * | wc -w
16
$ <insert command here>
test1 10
test2 6
$
```

or something similar regarding the output. As this will be on her university machine, I cannot code anything in perl or so, just shell is allowed. My shell knowledge is a bit rusty, so I cannot come up with a better solution - maybe you could be of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Ho n * | uniq -c
```

produces

```
 10 test1:n
  6 test2:n
```

If you want exactly your output:

```
grep -Ho n * | uniq -c | while read count file; do echo "${file%:n} $count"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly elegant, but the most obvious solution is:

```
letter='n'
for file in *; do
    count=`grep -o $letter "$file" | wc -w`
    echo "$file contains $letter $count times"
done
```

Comment: `for file in *` is preferable to `for file in $(ls)` -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

Glen's answer is far better for the flavors of UNIX that support it.  This will work on a UNIX that claims it is POSIX-compliant.  This is meant for the poor folks for whom the other answer does not fly.
POSIX grep says nothing about `grep -H -o`  See: `http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html`

Get a list of the files you want call it list.txt.  I chose the character ^  == shift 6 for no reason

```
while read fname
do
  cnt=`tr -dc '^' < $fname | wc -c`
  echo "$fname: $cnt"
done < list.txt
```